# Firebase User Uploads and Profile Pictures

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

Hello looking for some help,

I currently have some JavaScript code that allows a signed in user to upload an image to Firebase storage. I want the image that they upload to be their profile picture, however I don't seem to be able to link the uploaded image back to the specific user?

It works, I can see the uploaded image in the console, but nothing to identify what user uploaded it.

```
//Upload Profile Picture 
//Altered code from: Firebase Youtube Channel. 

      //Get Elements
      var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
      var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton');

      //Listen for file 
      fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e){

         //Get File
         var file = e.target.files[0];


         //Create a Storage Ref
         var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('profilePictures/' + file.name);

         //Upload file
         var task = storageRef.put(file);

         var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;        

         //Update Progress Bar 
         task.on('state_changed', 

         function progress(snapshot){
            var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) *100;
            uploader.value = percentage;

            //if percentage = 100
            //$(".overlay").hide();         
         },

         function error(err){

         },

         function complete(){

         }

       );           
    });


//Display Profile Picture   

function showUserDetails(){

   var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
   var name, photoUrl;

   if (user != null) {
      name = user.displayName;
      photoUrl = user.photoURL;

      document.getElementById('dp').innerHTML=photoURL;
      document.getElementById('username').innerHTML=name;  
}}
```

I saw the code below in the Firebase documentation, but I don't understand how to update the photo URL image or display it.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var name, email, photoUrl, uid;

if (user != null) {
   name = user.displayName;
   email = user.email;
   photoUrl = user.photoURL;
   uid = user.uid; // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
    // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
    // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
}
```

Many thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: So you ran the code in browser? I think you need to use firebase's db to record the following image url in db.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You'll want to store the files by username:

```
// Get current username
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

// Create a Storage Ref w/ username
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(user + '/profilePicture/' + file.name);

// Upload file
var task = storageRef.put(file);
```

So if the user is `user:12345` and the file name is `profile.jpg`, then the file will be saved as `user:12345/profilePicture/profile.jpg`. You can protect this with [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/) as follows:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/<your-firebase-storage-bucket>/o {
    match /{userId}/profilePicture/{fileName} {
      // Anyone can read
      allow read;
      // Only the user can upload their own profile picture
      // Profile picture must be of content-type "image/*"
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId
                   && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.+');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just trying to implement the security code you provided and im getting an error. On line nine it says unexpected '/.+".

Comment: That's what I get for writing regex's without testing them first--no need for the \ since the / doesn't need to be escaped. Updated the code and tested the deployment.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this solution, what would be the code to display the photo right in the same page as the uploader and what would be the controller's code to display it in another page like the profile page ? (I am using the initial upload at sign up just after the registration complete) Thank you !

Comment: @FrenchyNYC that's a whole other question. I recommend taking a look at our web codelab and getting a hang of Firebase: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#0

Comment: `firebase.storage().ref(user.uid + '/profilePicture/' + file.name)`