# What would be a good way to retrieve and display user-specific images that are stored in firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm making an Android app that displays a user's profile info. I am able to store the images on Cloud Storage, but I am not sure of how to retrieve and display the user-specific images that are stored in Cloud Storage.

One of the main problems I am facing is that `user.getPhotoUrl()` is not giving me the right uri. It gives me something of the form com.google.android.gms. and so on.

I have tried using Glide to display the images. But, it did not work as I was getting a FileNotFoundException. So, I tried using Glide with StorageReference.

But, the problem with using StorageReference is that I have to explicitly provide the uri of the image, while I want to retrieve the image specific to a user.

I expected the profile picture selected by the user to show up on the profile page, but when I run the app on Android Studio, nothing shows up.

Comment: The general approach is as followed, you can use the method from @Asad Ali Choudhry to upload the image to Firebase storage, when you get back the storage url Store this in your database (firestore or realtime) for the user.
So whenever you retrieve the user's information you also get the image url. Which you can display in your app.

Comment: @Egghead I also faced the similar problem. Do you know why is the function getPhotoUrl() not returning the correct value? Or am I not interpreting it's output correctly?

Comment: @PHcoDer what is it returning? have you set the value correctly? Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214447/firebase-user-uploads-and-profile-pictures

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a method which upload bitmap to firebase storage in android and retrieve it url, please use this method to upload image and retrieve url, After that let me know if you face any issue.

```
public static void UploadBitmap(Activity activity, Bitmap bitmap, String serverFileName) {

        if (bitmap == null) {
            return;
        }

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
                // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
                String directory = "images/";

                StorageReference fileRef = storageRef.child(directory + serverFileName);

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {


                        UploadTask uploadTask = fileRef.putBytes(data);
                        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                                Log.e("oops","error in bitmap uploading");

                            }
                        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, etc.
                                // ...
                                // now download url first
                            }
                        });

                        Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    throw task.getException();
                                }

                                // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                                return fileRef.getDownloadUrl();
                            }
                        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                                    String stringUrl = downloadUri.toString();

                                    // Great image is uploaded and url is here, you can load image anywhere via this stringUrl with Glide or Picasso.

                                } else {
                                    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                                    Log.e("oops","error in url retrieval");
                                }
                            }
                        });


                    }
                });


            }
        });
        thread.start();




    }
```

Comment: did you try this? does it resolve your issue? Let me know if you face any problem. thanks.

Comment: Hi, in your solution, you have simultaneously uploaded and displayed the images. However, in my application, I have already uploaded a user's profile picture in another activity. Now, I have created another activity in which I want to display the profile pic that the user had uploaded. Can you please help me out in that?

Comment: You can do it in this way, use all my code, upload picture, Got its url as in above code, then save that url to some variable / arraylist / database & now on the activity where you want to use the picture, get saved url and display picture.

Comment: If you need any other help let me know. if it works please upvote & accept my answer. thanks.

Comment: Sorry for being a little late, but can you please explain the parameters you have passed to the function?

Comment: For Actrivity you can pass "this" or context. Next Bitmap is the image which you want to upload. Last one is the filename by which you want it to be saved on storage directory. Like "image.png" or "timestamp.png"